# Fitting triangular function with HeavisideTheta

Tags: fitting

I have a problem fitting a triangular function (like potential vs. time in cyclic voltammetry) with a [`HeavisideTheta`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HeavisideTheta.html) function. I just want to get used to [`HeavisideTheta`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HeavisideTheta.html)as I have to apply it later on, on more complex curves, but I already encounter problems.
This is what I have done so far:

```
data = {{0, 0}, {0.1, 0.1}, {0.2, 0.2}, {0.3, 0.3}, {0.4, 0.4}, 
        {0.5, 0.5}, {0.6, 0.6}, {0.7, 0.7}, {0.8, 0.8}, {0.9, 0.9}, 
        {1, 1}, {1.1, 0.9}, {1.2, 0.8}, {1.3, 0.7}, {1.4, 0.6}, 
        {1.5, 0.5}, {1.6, 0.4}, {1.7, 0.3}, {1.8, 0.2}, {1.9, 0.1}, {2, 0}}

pos[x_] := a*(x - x0)

neg[x_] := -b*(x - x0)

model = neg[x]*HeavisideTheta[x - x1] + pos[x]*(1 - HeavisideTheta[x - x1]);
langfit = NonlinearModelFit[data, neg[x]*HeavisideTheta[x - x1] + 
           pos[x]*(1 - HeavisideTheta[x - x1]), {a, b, x0, x1 }, x]
```

NonlinearModelFit returns:

> NonlinearModelFit::nrjnum: The Jacobian is not a matrix of real numbers at {a,b,x0,x1} = {1.,1.,1.,1.}. >>

```
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2 }, {-1, 2}}], Plot[langfit[x], {x, -2, 2}]]
```

Comment: Can you work with `UnitStep` instead of `HeavisideTheta` ? Also, I'd add a constant term (intercept) to your `pos` and `neg`.

Comment: As @b.gatessucks suggests, the basic problem is that `HeavisideTheta` is not defined for a zero argument, so you'll always run into this issue as long as you insist on using it. By all means use `HeavisideTheta` for any derivations if it makes it easier, but `UnitStep` is probably a better alternative for the fitting. I'm voting to close since the question seems not to involve any more complex issues than that.

Comment: @OleksandrR. not sure about closure. This is something other users might run into as well. Your comment might be very useful as (slightly expanded) answer.

Answer (score 3):

First add a constant term to `pos` and `neg` as b.gatessucks suggests.  Then you can bump the starting point of the parameter `x1` off of the data grid, so that `x - x1` is unlikely to ever be zero:

```
data = {{0, 0}, {0.1, 0.1}, {0.2, 0.2}, {0.3, 0.3}, {0.4, 0.4}, {0.5, 
    0.5}, {0.6, 0.6}, {0.7, 0.7}, {0.8, 0.8}, {0.9, 0.9}, {1, 
    1}, {1.1, 0.9}, {1.2, 0.8}, {1.3, 0.7}, {1.4, 0.6}, {1.5, 
    0.5}, {1.6, 0.4}, {1.7, 0.3}, {1.8, 0.2}, {1.9, 0.1}, {2, 0}};

pos[x_] := c + a*(x - x0);

neg[x_] := d - b*(x - x0);

model = neg[x]*HeavisideTheta[x - x1] + pos[x]*(1 - HeavisideTheta[x - x1]);

langfit = NonlinearModelFit[data, model, {a, b, c, d, x0, {x1, 1.01}}, x];

Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[langfit[x], {x, 0, 2}], Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or you could try the `"PrincipalAxis"` method, which doesn't use derivatives.  Here you need to use `UnitStep`, unless you change the starting point of `x1` as above.  However there is a discontinuous gap in the solution (in both the `UnitStep` and the `HeavisideTheta` models), which changes location if the initial value for `x1` is changed.  I couldn't get rid of the discontinuity.

```
langfit = 
  NonlinearModelFit[data, 
   neg[x]*UnitStep[x - x1] + pos[x]*(1 - UnitStep[x - x1]),
   {a, b, c, d, x0, {x1, 1.}}, x, Method -> "PrincipalAxis"];

Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[langfit[x], {x, 0, 2}], Frame -> True, 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0.1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]